# Помогите разобраться в ошибке: Существует назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который требуется предварительно закрыть

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

> Сведения об исключении: System.InvalidOperationException: Существует 
>   назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который
>   требуется  предварительно закрыть.

Ошибка источника:

```
namespace Library.Controls
{
    public partial class CategoryList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected IEnumerable<string> GetCategories()
        {


            return new Repository().namebook
                .Select(p => p.genre_book.NAME_GENRE)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x => x);
        }

        protected string CreateHomeLinkHtml()
        {
            string path = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, null).VirtualPath;
            return string.Format("<a href='{0}'>Главная</a>", path);
        }

        protected string CreateLinkHtml(string category)
        {
            string selectedCategory = (string)Page.RouteData.Values["category"]
              ?? Request.QueryString["category"];

            string path = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, null,
                new RouteValueDictionary() { { "category", category },
                    {"page", "1"} }).VirtualPath;

            return string.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>",
                path, category);
        }
    }
}
```

а вот так выглядит repository

```
public class Repository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<books> namebook
    {
        get { return context.namebook; }
    }
```

code-behind формы где я пытаюсь фильтровать книги

```
public IEnumerable<books> Getbook()
{
    return repository.namebook
        .OrderBy(b => b.ID_BOOK)
        .Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize);
}


private IEnumerable<books> FilterBook()
{
    IEnumerable<books> namebook = repository.namebook;
    string currentCategory = (string)RouteData.Values["category"] ??
        Request.QueryString["category"];
    return currentCategory == null ? namebook:
        namebook.Where(p => p.genre_book.NAME_GENRE == currentCategory);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Необходимо материализовать ваш запрос в любую коллекцию

```
return new Repository().namebook
    // для Distinct придется реализовать IEquatable<books>
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(p => p.genre_book.NAME_GENRE)
    .Select(p => p.genre_book.NAME_GENRE)
    .ToArray();
```

Пока вы не материализовали коллекцию, ваш запрос не выполнен и соответственно ридер не закрыт

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, добавил .OrderBy(x => x).ToArray(); все равно выдает туже ошибку

Comment: @alexyzolotarev покажите весь код вашего метода. или сами внимательно изучите, возможно ридер еще где-то открыт

Comment: дополнил вопрос полным кодом

Comment: @alexyzolotarev, а ну все верно, операция Select должна быть перед материализацией, сейчас подправлю ответ

Answer (score 4):

Когда вы перебираете элементы в последовательности без предварительной материализации (`.ToList()`) - то все это время висит открытый DataReader с результатами запроса к БД.

В тот момент, когда EF пытается сделать ленивую загрузку - делается еще один запрос к БД. Тут-то и срабатывает ограничение - в каждом соединении с БД может быть только один активный запрос.

Если вы используете MS SQL Server, то можно дописать к строке подключения параметр `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` - это снимет ограничение.

Для других СУБД такой ситуации нужно избегать. Например, через предварительную материализацию запросов (т.е. расстановку этих `.ToList()`).

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь быстро выполнить один и тот же запрос дважды (предыдущий еще не успел отработать). Обычно данная проблема появляется с весьма тяжелыми запросами. Чтобы включить данную возможность надо подправить ConnectionString - добавьте "MultipleActiveResultSets=True".

Подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx).

P.S.
Ранняя материализации - это не всегда хорошо.