# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Есть следующий метод:

```
public static bool IfStudentHasProblems(CollegeContext db, Student student, ControlPoint cp)
{
    foreach (var mark in db.Marks.Where(m => m.Student.StudentId == student.StudentId))
    {
        if (mark.ControlPoint == cp && mark.Value < 4)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

При обращении к db.Marks выбрасывает исключкение выше.
Код вызывающий метод:

```
private void groupComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (groupComboBox.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(groupComboBox.SelectedItem);
        selectedGroup = db.Groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Number == num);

        studentListView.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var student in db.Students.Where(s => s.Group.Number == selectedGroup.Number).OrderBy(s => s.LastName).ThenBy(s => s.FirstName))
            if (CalculationUtils.IfStudentHasProblems(db, student, selectedCP))
                studentListView.Items.Add(student.LastName + " " + student.FirstName).BackColor = Color.Goldenrod;
            else
                studentListView.Items.Add(student.LastName + " " + student.FirstName);

        if (selectedCP != null)
            WriteStatistics();
    }
    else
    {
        selectedGroup = null;
        studentListView.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

Так же есть похожий метод, который выполняется без ошибок:

```
public static int CountStudentsWithBadMarks(CollegeContext db, Group group, ControlPoint cp)
{
    int c = 0;
    foreach (var m in db.Marks.Where(m => m.Student.Group.Number == group.Number))
        if (m.ControlPoint.Date == cp.Date)
            if (m.Value < 4)
                c++;
    return c;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, где ошибка и как исправить.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такое происходит потому что вы пытаетесь делать один запрос к БД в то время пока идет перебор результатов другого запроса к БД.

Если посмотреть какие запросы к БД вы делаете, то получится как-то вот так:

```
foreach (var student in db.Students.Where(...))
{
    foreach (var mark in db.Marks.Where(m => m.Student.StudentId == student.StudentId)) 
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Исправить проблему можно несколькими способами:

1. *(не работает для MySQL)* разрешить соединению иметь несколько открытых дата ридеров - добавить `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` в строку подключения к БД;
2. материализовать внешний запрос

   ```
   foreach (var student in db.Students.Where(...).ToList())
   {
       foreach (var mark in db.Marks.Where(m => m.Student.StudentId == student.StudentId)) 
       {
            // ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. использовать навигационные свойства вместо дополнительных запросов совместно с eager loading:

   ```
   foreach (var student in db.Students.Where(...).Include(s => s.Marks))
   {
       foreach (var mark in student.Marks) 
       {
            // ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Да, я уже разобрался, как раз с помощью ToList(). Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Классический ответ, более поздние ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472559/213987)) можно было бы даже придубликатить сюда.

Comment: Мне кажется тут лучше использовать Join

Comment: @B.Vandyshev а зачем тут Join?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Вы сначала делаете запрос к бд, потом для каждого из элементов делаете еще по запросу, а могли бы сделать все одним запросом

Comment: @B.Vandyshev третий вариант загружает все одним запросом

Answer (score -1):

Также для решения данной проблемы, можно использовать разные объекты контекста базы данных. В вашем случае, наверно, как-то так

```
public static bool IfStudentHasProblems(Student student, ControlPoint cp)
{
    using (var db = new CollegeContext())
    {
        foreach (var mark in db.Marks.Where(m => m.Student.StudentId == student.StudentId))
        {
            if (mark.ControlPoint == cp && mark.Value < 4)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

Но в комментариях подсказывают, что контекст нежелательно создавать в цикле из-за возможного снижения производительности. Ну значит можно вынести создание контекста за цикл.

```
using (var db2 = new CollegeContext())
{ 
    foreach (var student in db.Students
                              .Where(s => s.Group.Number == selectedGroup.Number)
                              .OrderBy(s => s.LastName)
                              .ThenBy(s => s.FirstName))            
    {
        if (CalculationUtils.IfStudentHasProblems(db2, student, selectedCP))
        {
            studentListView.Items.Add(student.LastName + " " + student.FirstName)
                                 .BackColor = Color.Goldenrod;
        }
        else
        {
            studentListView.Items.Add(student.LastName + " " + student.FirstName);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**P.S.**
Кстати, я не утверждаю, что это хорошие варианты в данном случае. Однако они тоже помогут решить проблему и могут быть полезны в некоторых других ситуациях.

Comment: Открывать несколько контекстов к базе в цикле? Совсем не оптимальное решение с точки зрения производительности.

Comment: @Anamnian, возможно вы правы, не могу сказать. Я использовал это решение в цикле, где каждая итерация и так не быстрая, и поэтому не заметил просадку.