# connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#

И снова привет. Мой прошлый вопрос был построен некорректно, как возможно и этот. Не кидайтесь помидорами, пожалуйста. Я только начал изучать Сишарп и впервые открыл для себя стаковерфлоу. Я думаю будет лучше, если вы объясните, что я как-то не так задал вопрос или что-то не докинул. Спасибо.

```cs
var database = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(@ "server=123;
    user = 123; database = 123; port = 123; password = 123;
    "); //данные для входа в бд

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(); //создание переменной для удобства
    int used = 0; MySqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand(); //команда для бд
    var a = cmnd.ExecuteReader(); //чтение из бд
    string HWIDlocal = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value; //получаем хвид компа
    string HWID = $ "UPDATE LoginedChuvaku SET HWID = {HWIDlocal} WHERE ID = '{a.GetString("
    UID ")}'"; //изменение значения в бд
    string useeed = $ "UPDATE LoginedChuvaku SET used = {used} WHERE ID = {a.GetString("
    UID ")}"; //изменение значения used в бд
    con.ConnectionString = database.ConnectionString; //подключение к бд
    con.Open(); //открыть бд
    MySqlCommand hwid = new MySqlCommand(HWID, con); //команда для изменения хвида
    MySqlCommand useed = new MySqlCommand(useeed, con); //команда для изменения значения used в бд

    while (a.Read()) {
      if (a.GetInt32("used") == used) {
        hwid.ExecuteNonQuery();
        useed.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Clipboard.SetText(HWID);
        //дебаг      MessageBox.Show($"HWID установлен {HWID} {HWIDlocal} {a.GetString("UID")} {used}");
        con.Close();
      } else {
        MessageBox.Show("HWID уже установлен.");
        con.Close();
      }
    }
```

Обновленный код, с которым все работает:

```cs
private protected bool PseudoProverka(string login, string pass) {
    try {
        var database = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(@ "server=123;
        user = 123; database = 123; port = 123; password = 123;
        ");

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(); //создание переменной для удобства
        int used = 0; int used1 = 1; con.ConnectionString = database.ConnectionString; //подключение к бд
        con.Open(); //открытие бд
        MySqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand(); //команда для бд
        cmnd.CommandText = $ "SELECT * FROM LoginedChuvaku WHERE Login = '{login}'"; //получаю информацию из бд по логину
        var a = cmnd.ExecuteReader(); //чтение из бд
        string HWIDlocal = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value; //получаем хвид компа

        while (a.Read()) {
            if (a.GetInt32("used") == used) {
            string HWID = $ "UPDATE `LoginedChuvaku` SET `HID` = '{HWIDlocal}' WHERE `LoginedChuvaku`.`UID` = {a.GetString("
            UID ")}"; //изменение значения в бд
            string useeed = $ "UPDATE `LoginedChuvaku` SET `used` = '{used1}' WHERE `LoginedChuvaku`.`UID` = {a.GetString("
            UID ")}"; //изменение значения used в бд 
            MySqlCommand hwid = new MySqlCommand(HWID, con); //команда для изменения хвида в бд
            MySqlCommand useed = new MySqlCommand(useeed, con); //команда для изменения значения used в бд
            a.Close();
            hwid.ExecuteNonQuery();
            useed.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } else {
            MessageBox.Show("HWID уже установлен.");
            }
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `con.Open();` должно быть выполнено до `cmnd.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: В забыли принять ответ в прошлом вашем вопросе. Чтобы дополнить вопрос, его не обязательно удалять и пересоздавать, его можно отредактировать.

Comment: @aepot Ещё не могу. Нужно подождать 17 часов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, но теперь другая ошибка. Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: Строку `con.ConnectionString = database.ConnectionString;` вы конечно же не перенесли выше

Comment: @eco а что, тот ответ, который вам был дан другим участником - бесполезный? или вы только свои ответы принимаете?

Comment: @aepot не говорю, что он бесполезный, но я думал нужно помечать ответами только, то, что помогло мне. Извиняюсь, если что-то не так.

Comment: @eco но в том вашем ответе нет решения, есть только абстрактное объяснение. Он бесполезен для других посетителей. Вы пришли в базу знаний, и наверняка сами ей пользуетесь, когда используете поиск. Давайте вопросы и ответы учитывая этот факт.

Comment: @aepot Учту, спасибо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я Вас, наверно, уже замучал, но у меня еще одна проблема. `The commandtext property has not been properly initialized`.

Comment: Вы создаёте пустой `cmnd`. Учитывая, что потом вызываете у него `ExecuteReader`, там наверняка должен быть sql-запрос `SELECT ...`. Для `hwid` и `useed` вы же задаёте sql.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov честно говоря мне уже стыдно спрашивать Вас, но..
`invalid attempt to access a field before calling read()` Как я понял, оно возвращает пустое значение. Но вроде всё верно. `MySqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand(); //команда для бд
                cmnd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM LoginedChuvaku WHERE Login = '{login}'";
                var a = cmnd.ExecuteReader(); //чтение из бд
                while (a.Read()){
                           ...
                }`

Comment: Переменная login не возвращает пустое значение (не могу почему-то отредактировать старый комментарий).

Comment: Прежде чем использовать `a.GetString` нужно вызвать `a.Read()`.

Comment: Не пишите код в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос. Напишите код, который получился теперь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вопрос отредактировал. Но появилась еще одна ошибка :/
`there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first`.

Попробовал сделать как в этом вопросе `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721242/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connection-which-must-b`, но не работает. Выдает ошибку, что и в названии этого вопроса. 

Спасибо большое, что всё ещё пытаетесь помочь мне.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо большое за помощь. Проблема решена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я могу судить, ваш код обновляет колонки `HID` и `used` у найденной записи с логином и значением `used` равным нулю.

Это можно сделать одним запросом UPDATE. Не нужно делать предварительный SELECT.

```
string sql = @"UPDATE `LoginedChuvaku`
               SET `HID` = @hid, `used` = 1
               WHERE `Login` = @login AND `used` = 0";

string hwid = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;

using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (MySqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmnd.CommandText = sql;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("hid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = hwid;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login;

        int rowsAffected = cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Постараюсь объяснить, что тут к чему.

Не нужно создавать `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` при каждом вызове метода. Строку соединения следует получить в конструкторе класса и сохранить в поле. Далее просто используем это поле `_connectionString`.

Ресурсы нужно обязательно освобождать. Для этого `MySqlConnection` и `MySqlCommand` обёрнуты в `using`. Пока просто скопируйте, со временем поймёте, почему это необходимо.

Значения переменных `used` и `used1` фактически являются константами, т. к. никогда не меняются, поэтому я просто перенёс их в sql-запрос.

А вот значения для `Login` и `HID` следует задавать параметрами. Это обезопасит от sql-инъекций и в целом ускорит выполнение множества запросов.
Я указал тип параметров `MySqlDbType.VarChar` - замените его на тот, который указан в таблице БД (я не могу знать точный тип).

Метод `ExecuteNonQuery` возвращает количество задействованных строк. Можете добавить в код проверку, что-то вроде:

```
if (rowsAffected >= 1)
{
    // обновление произошло
}
else
{
    // обновление не произошло
}
```

Вставьте в ветки `if` нужную реакцию.

---

Ваш метод принимает параметр `string pass`, но никак его не использует. Вероятно, его следует или удалить, или использовать в запросе в `WHERE`.

Ваш метод возвращает параметр `bool`. Но никогда не возвращает `true`. Вероятно, метод следует сделать `void`.

Старайтесь давать говорящие имена переменным. `used1`, `useed` - плохие название.
Также мне не очень понятны аббревиатуры `hid`, `hwid`. Имхо, там должен быть `sid` - security identifier.

Имена `LoginedChuvaku` и `PseudoProverka` тоже надо бы заменить.

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь применить все, что вы сказали. Насчёт `string pass` и метод `bool`. У меня здесь не весь код указан, а только то с чем была проблема.

Comment: У меня к вам ещё два вопроса, если вы, конечно, не против. Как я могу занести полное время вплоть до секунд в бд ? Пробовал `DateTime.Now`, но оно не особо хочет.  ||

Ещё мне нужно из бд взять текст, но если я использую `"string res = $"SELECT res FROM LoginedChuvaku WHERE Login = '{login}'";`, то получаю эту же строчку, что и написано, а не текст, который мне нужен. Эта строчка, если это нужно, идет после `cmnd.CommandText = ...`.

Чёрт, почему в комментариях не работают абзацы(

Comment: @eco - задайте новый вопрос. Там и опишете всё красиво, с абзацами.

Comment: да, я создал его.