# Использование lazy loading entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте, создал консольное приложение с entity framework. Для загрузки данных использую принцип lazy load. И всё работает если написать вот так вот:

```
Context db = new Context();
            var teams = db.Teams.ToList();
            foreach(Team t in teams)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Team named is {0} ", t.Name);
                foreach(Player p in t.Players)
                    Console.WriteLine("In team {0}, have player {1}", t.Name, p.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

То есть я в в варовскую переменную гружу лист команд, и к ней всё подтягивается. И когда я перебираю всё в цикле всё норм, но если я буду грузить не лист, а iqueryable, то есть вот так вот:
`var teams = db.Teams;` В таком случае будет ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит? Почему я не могу получить из такого вида данных коллекцию игроков?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81k7Q.png

Comment: @tym32167 `Существует назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который требуется предварительно закрыть` вот что в innerexception, что это значит, не могу понять.

Comment: [Пробовали искать](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5+Command+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9+DataReader%2C+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите разобраться в ошибке: Существует назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который требуется предварительно закрыть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472559/)

Comment: @tym32167 ну там по сути и советуют то что у меня в первом варианте. Но во втором варианте я же могу бегать по всем командам, почему же для того что бы пролезть в коллекции нужно обязательно привести например к листу этот запрос?

Comment: Заходим в тот вопрос, читаем там ответ `Необходимо материализовать ваш запрос в любую коллекцию`, `Пока вы не материализовали коллекцию, ваш запрос не выполнен и соответственно ридер не закрыт`

Comment: то есть вы пытаетесь лениво читать сразу и команды, и игроков. Так нельзя, надо читать что то одно, потом что то другое

Comment: А чтобы читать и то и другое сразу одним ридером, надо пользоваться методом Include, например `var teams = db.Teams.Include(t=>t.Players);` Это позволит при считывании команды сразу грузить игроков, то есть как бы за 1 чтение, а не несколько

Comment: Подробнее про загрузку связанных сущностей [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score -1):

Как правильно заметил [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167), "необходимо материализовать запрос в коллекцию", из сырого IQueryable. Из-за ленивой загрузки, данные в IQueryable не подгружаются полностью, пока их не представишь в коллекцию. Например в List. Подробней можно почитать [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level3/3_4.php).

*upd.* Возможно, вам поможет такой код:

```
var players = db.Teams
    .Include(x=>x.Players) // включает в себя игроков (и тогда их можно прочитать из IQueryable и/или преобразовать в список)
```

Либо собрать только игроков, сразу в коллекцию:

```
var players = db.Teams
    .SelectMany(x=>x.Players)
    .ToList();
```

В любом случае, оставлять запрос как IQueryable, для передачи куда-либо, не рекомендуется.